# Set application exit code / errorlevel from WinForms app being run as a console app

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application, .net-4.6.1

How can I set an application exit code from a Winforms app that I am running as a console app? Without breaking the console app into a separate DLL of course.

I have a Winforms app. In the past someone decided to create command line parameters that will run it as a console app instead of a WinForms app. I know that breaking it out into a separate console app project is a solution, but without that, is there a way to set the application exit code?

I tried:

1. Having main return an int
2. Calling Environment.Exit(int)
3. Setting Environment.ExitCode = int

None worked.

Then of course from the command line I ran the command below. But the error code was not updating.

> echo %errorlevel%

```
public static class Program
{
    // defines for commandline output
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

    private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // redirect console output to parent process;
        // must be before any calls to Console.WriteLine()
        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);

        //make sure to update 0 to another number to make sure you aren't getting a false positive
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Environment.Exit([Some Exit Value]);` before `return [something];` will return the Exit Code. If you `[Process].Start -> [Process].WaitForExit -> Console.WriteLine([Process].ExitCode)`.

Comment: A third party app is reading the errorlevel. I don't want to write a wrapper

Comment: Using a `.cmd` batch, start the application; right after, insert `echo %errorlevel%`, after that `pause`. You will see the value you have set in `Environment.Exit()` printed in the Console.