# Calling a WinForms VB.NET application from a command line or from a script

Tags: vb.net, winforms, console-application, exit-code

I have a VB.NET legacy software. I want to add a feature, where you can just run the application with an execution parameter/command line argument and it will perform some database updates and then shut down again.

Actually, the functionality itself is meaningless for my question.
The important part is, that for this, no GUI is needed.
Rather, I may want to use the new feature by running the application from a script, in which case I want to return some output (from application to script), so that the script knows if the execution was successful or not. The most obvious kind of output that came to mind was returning an exit code.

I've researched quite a bit for this problem but so far, I couldn't find a solution that I liked (assume I want to return exit code 42):

- Using `Environment.Exit(42)` to shut down the application and then `echo %errorlevel%` to output the exit code on a Windows console always gave an output of 0
- Changing the application's "Output type" setting from WinForms to Console Application would actually work in that it does set the exit code correctly. However, it *feels* wrong and when the actual application is started, an additional (unwanted) console opens up.
- Adding a new project, which would be the needed console application, also seems problematic as linking to all needed modules, etc. from the legacy software is quickly getting out of hand.

What would be the cleanest solution/best practice for my problem?
Is the problem so unusual?
Are there any issues with my thought process?

---

[edit]:
For testing, I'm using an otherwise blank, new WinForms application, that exits immediately:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Environment.Exit(42)
End Sub
```

Then i run the generated .exe in a console and check the exit code with `echo %errorlevel%`. It's always 0.

Comment: Using Winforms is a problem, the command interpreter doesn't wait until the program terminates.  And therefore can't correctly report the errorlevel, it hasn't been set yet.  Use [start /wait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) to force it to wait.

Comment: If you disable Application Framework and start from your Sub Main, you can read the `args` argument and decide what to do. If, e.g., `args.Count > 0`, you do something with the arguments and call `Environment.Exit()` in the end, without showing a Form. `echo %errorlevel%` will print that value

Comment: i found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54913906/set-application-exit-code-errorlevel-from-winforms-app-being-run-as-a-console which sounds like it's basically what i'm asking. @Jimi you commented there as well and i might try what you suggested there.

Comment: It's kind of the same thing I've written here (I forgot about that other post), but that's a C# app, there's no Application Framework by default :)

Comment: i added further explanation on how i'm testing any possible solutions. checking the CommandLineArgs is not a problem, neither is using ´Environment.Exit()´ or ´echo %errorlevel%´. disabling Application Framework unfortunately didn't help. i tried playing around with start /wait, as suggested by @HansPassant, but it didn't do anything for me, either.

Comment: If you disabled Application Framework, then you added your own `Sub Main(args as String())`, right? Set as the starting procedure in the Project's properties (also check whether `Application.Designer.vb` has been updated, should be empty) -- Try to use a `.cmd` file, start it in a Console window. In the `.cmd`, start your application with a command parameter, show a MessageBox with, e.g., the length of `args`, then call `Environment.Exit()` -- If the length is `0`, you `Application.Run()` your Form instead

Comment: start /wait windowsformsapp1.exe, followed by echo %errorlevel% worked just fine when I tried it.  It is *required* to properly retrieve the errorlevel, we can't see what you tried.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for that pointer. i was too stupid to understand the correct order for running start /wait. using your order it also worked for me, at least using my sample code. now to trying that with the real code... either way, thank you, helped a lot!

Comment: @Jimi disabling Application Framework and setting a different starting procedure are not things i want to do on the legacy software. i want to run it, supplying a command line parameter, which would trigger the new functionality, still leaving the regular functionality totally untouched.

Comment: Consider using a command line parser. See https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline

Comment: I hope your business logic is not mixed up with your GUI, otherwise, you will have to mimic clicking on buttons and the like by invoking the event handlers. That would be a quick and dirty way to achieve what you want.